# Loading a very large txt file and taking transpose

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a tab separated .txt file that keeps numbers as matrix. Number of lines is 904,652 and the number of columns is 26,600 (tab separated). The total size of the file is around 48 GB. I need to load this file as matrix and take the transpose of the matrix to extract training and testing data. I am using Python, pandas, and `sklearn` packages. I behave 500GB memory server but it is not enough to load it with pandas package. Could anyone help me about my problem?

The loading code part is below:

```
def open_with_pandas_read_csv(filename):
    df = pandas.read_csv(filename, sep=csv_delimiter, header=None)
    data = df.values
    return data
```

Comment: I added the code part that loads the file into the memory. I believe there should be a preprocessing part to reduce the size of the file before loading it.

Comment: What datatype do yo need `float64`, or `int32` or something else?

Comment: Isn't that matrix sparse? Do you have lot of 0's in it?

Also this might be useful: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk

Comment: Yes, it is a sparse matrix. What do you suggest me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution (I believe there are still more efficient and logical ones) on stackoverflow. `np.fromfile()` method loads huge files more efficiently more than `np.loadtxt()` and `np.genfromtxt()` and even `pandas.read_csv()`. It took just around 274 GB without any modification or compression. I thank everyone who tried to help me on this issue.

Answer (score 2):

If your server has 500GB of RAM, you should have no problem using numpy's [loadtxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) method.

```
data = np.loadtxt("path_to_file").T
```

Comment: I will try and let you know what happened.

Comment: I tested it and It failed.

Comment: Did you run out of memory or did something else happen?

Comment: It was still running and there was only around 200MB free memory. That's why I killed it.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it's a text file makes it a little harder. As a first step, I would create a binary file out of it, where each number takes a constant number of bytes. It will probably also reduce the file size.

Then, I would make a number of passes, and in each pass I would write N rows in the output file.

Pseudo code:

```
transposed_rows = [ [], .... , [] ] # length = N    
for p in range(columns / N):
    for row in range(rows):
        x = read_N_numbers_from_row_of_input_matrix(row,pass*N)
        for i in range(N):
             transposed_rows[i].append(x)
    for i in range(N):
       append_to_output_file(transposed_rows[i])
```

The transformation to binary file enables to read a sequence of numbers from the middle of the row.

N should be small enough to fit transposed_rows() in memory, i.e. N*rows should be reasonable.

N should be large enough so that we take advantage of caching. If N=1, this means we're wasting a lot of reads to generate a single row of output.

Comment: Note that `pass` is a keyword in python, so not a good chose for a variable name :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me that your are working on genetic data. If so, consider using --transpose with plink, it is very quick: http://pngu.mgh.harvard.edu/~purcell/plink/dataman.shtml#recode